# define size limit for Azure blob stream i.e. truncate the file

Tags: node.js, azure, stream, azure-blob-storage

I was wondering if there are some features available to specify max length for azure blob stream so that only specified size gets uploaded and rest is discarded i.e. the file gets truncated  .

**Question**

My need is to specify max size for a file say 50 or 60 Mb and I want the file to get truncated if the size is maximum. (Files can be large log files or video files)

I have following code working ( I am using multiparty for form and azure-storage node package for azure)

```
// form.on is from multiparty

form.on('part', function(part) {
     var streamLength = 25 * 1024 * 1024; // part.byteCount
     if (part.filename) {
        form.on('part', function(part) {
             if (part.filename) {
                blobService.createBlockBlobFromStream(container,
                        blobName, part, streamLength, 
                        function(err, blobContent, blob) {
                     if (err) {
                        // do sth with error
                     }
                     return blobContent;
                 });
             } else {
                    form.handlePart(part);
             }
        });
     } else {
        form.handlePart(part);
     }
});
```

**Scenario:**

If `streamLength` is specified to be below 29 Mb(in example 25 Mb) then when I upload say video of 80 Mb then I get the desired result i.e. only 25 Mb of the file gets upload i.e. video file gets truncated.

But if I specify size to be greater than 29 Mb then the `streamLength` doesn't matter and whole file is being uploaded.

I tried looking at `azure-storage` and found that if `streamLength` is specified more than `DEFAULT_SINGLE_BLOB_PUT_THRESHOLD_IN_BYTES: 32* 1024 * 1024` then library tries to put the blob in chunks by separating them into blocks and if it is below `DEFAULT_SINGLE_BLOB_PUT_THRESHOLD_IN_BYTES` then it tries to put the whole block at once.

**Is there a way to achieve this functionality?**

**Edit**

Testing uploading 80 Mb of file

> streamLength = 28 Mb (< 29 Mb) : 28 Mb of file gets uploaded
>
> streamLength = 32 Mb (>= 32 Mb): 80 Mb of file gets uploaded

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reporting this and we apologize for the inconvenience. We have confirmed that this is a bug in Azure Storage Client Library.

Comment: Seems like I had changed something in the library. I cannot reproduce `RangeError` too. I have corrected the question.

Comment: Thank you for following up. And I edited the answer accordingly. We are working on a fix and it will be in an upcoming release.